How to show red alert text under the input if input value is not right. In reacts and Nextjs
               <input
                  aria-required
                  className="bg-white text-black h-40px text-lg hover:border-blue-400 border-solid border-b-2 w-[87%] "
                  id=""
                  placeholder=""
                  value={desc}
                  onChange={(e) => setDesc(e.target.value)}
                  required
                />


                <button className="p-2 w-[20%] rounded-2xl bg-blue-500 text-white border-0 outline-none hover:bg-blue-400 " onClick={handleAddTodo}>
                    Add
                </button>

Can some one show me little example? I will really appreciate it.

Simple way to do it is to create a useState  and validate input in onChange function.
Add a text below  like {errorMessage && <p className='text-red'>{errormessage}</p>

You can add conditional class like so:
<input className={`bg-white ${isInvaid ? 'text-red' : 'text-black'} h-40px text-lg hover:border-blue-400 border-solid border-b-2 w-[87%]`}/>


Thanks but can you give me more details. I'm really stuck here. IsInvalid- what is this

isInvalid is a flag to check if the input is valid or not.

But it's not working. It says "Cannot find name 'isInvaid'." Am I missing something? Sorry I am beginner

You have to create a state using useState

Thank you again. I did it few hours ago.
